# Global variables are undefined for imported Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Trying to figure out if there is a problem due to the import/export method, or if my architecture just bad....

Previously, I had multiple files of javascript. Just functions, no classes. In one "center/main" JS file, there are global variables. These variables are accessed and used/updated by functions in that same file, as well as other files. Each JS file had to have its own  tag within the index.html

**The move was then to switch to webpack as a module builder** which would remove the need for all those script tags. Instead I just have to import/export the functions.

---

**The problem is that now after using that method, the global variables are undefined to the imported functions** Below is the setup dumbed down, but I don't see why it would be a problem. Maybe I'm missing something.

## *main JS file*

```
import * as SettingsFile from './settings';

var myVariableUsed;

$(document).ready(function() {
  myVariableUsed = "test";
  SettingsFile.startSettings();
});
```

## *secondary JS file* (settings.js)

```
export function startSettings(json) {
   console.log(myVariableUsed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy, i think you can understant what is happening with this article:

https://medium.com/webpack/brief-introduction-to-scope-hoisting-in-webpack-8435084c171f

To be short, webpack creates a new scope for required files, because of 'use strict' declaration on generated code output.

To pass parâmeters to required modules you need to do do something like this:

```
// somefile
require("lib.js")(param1, param2)
// lib.js
module.exports = function(param1, param2) { }
```